# Failed to resolve channel name (Spring, Rabbit)

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a problem when I try to send a message to rabbit queue, I get the next exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: failed to resolve channel name 'userManager';
nested exception is
   org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException:
       failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'userManager' in the BeanFactory.;
   nested exception is
       org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
           No bean named 'userManager' is defined
```

In my local environment and in my partner environment all works fine but when I send the message to the DEV and QA environment (AWS), that exception is throws, I had tried a lot of things such as restart the components, change the name of my service activator, restart rabbit server, restart mongo. I don't know if this problem is of rabbit configuration so if someone can help me with this I really appreciate.

Comment: It's not to do with Rabbit. It's purely a Spring configuration issue.

Comment: Do you have different Spring configurations for different environments? Which environments have no definition for the `userManager` bean (of type `MessageChannel`)

Comment: You need to show your configuration and a full stack trace - edited stack traces are rarely useful.